# How to get entity in diapason of date?

Tags: jquery, sql, datetime, timezone, logic

I have query:

```
expiration >: '01-01-2022' and expiration <:  '09-01-2022'
```

My database:

```
id | customer_id | type | expiration |
1  | 1           | Test | 03-01-2022 |
2  | 2           |Test2 | 05-01-2022 |
3  | 3           |Test3 | 05-05-2022 |
```

I want to receive :

```
1  | 1 | Test | 03-01-2022 |
2  | 2 |Test2 | 05-01-2022 |
```

But, I get:

```
1  | 1 | Test | 03-01-2022 |
2  | 2 |Test2 | 05-01-2022 |
3  | 3 |Test3 | 05-05-2022 |
```

Can you help me?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what dialect of SQL you are using. But the query looks fine except unusual operators `>:` and `<:`. Why not use `>=` and `<=`.

I would recommend to look into datetime format used. Is it DD-MM-YYYY, or MM-DD-YYYY? It depends on your database locale. The most usual format is YYYY-MM-DD, but that's probably not your case, because it would select nothing.

Comment: There may be an error in the storage type?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the format and now it searches correctly)

```
Was: dd-MM-yyyy
Now: yyyy-MM-dd
```